# I am a Java biginer , can any one tell me what happening in background when we run java web application with IDE(Netbeans,Eclipse)

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a Java biginer , can any one tell me what  happening in background when we run java web application with IDE(Netbeans,Eclipse),

Actually I know run web applications, but i don't know  wt happening background. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your web application has a local server on your machine, when you start server it loads web.xml file,web.xml file present in WebProject --> webcontent --> WEBINF ,
web.xml file has all the information of your web application.

Comment: After web.xml file loading wt happens

Comment: when your application completely deployed to server then it depends on your web application,like if you have used `Filter`(it will be called on every new request) after request you will get response from server.

Answer (score 0):

An application server such as `glassfish` starts, then the `IDE` deploys the web application on it so you can test it.

Answer (score 0):

your web application has a local server on your machine. Your IDE hold the files in there and launch your application